# C# Regular Expression Customize

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using C# .Net in Visual Studio. I want to create a regular expression for these (Examples: AA-01, AC-02, AZ-09). That is (two Uppercase Character - Two Numeric Digit).

I tried code below but I'm not getting proper result

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
if (new Regex(@"^([A-Z])-([0-9])$").IsMatch(this.textBoxItemCode.Text.Trim()) == false)    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Proper Item 
    textBoxItemCode.Focus();
}
```

Comment: You can use [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test your regex. At the moment your are only matching `A-1`, `A-2`, `Z-9`.

Comment: `"^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"`

Comment: `if (!Regex.IsMatch(this.textBoxItemCode.Text.Trim(), @"^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"))`...

Comment: Thanks for share your valuable time and knowledge.

Comment: You are using ^ and $. So the given string should contain only "AA-01" like this. And the given pattern is incorrect. It will select only one upper case alphabet, one hyphen and one number.

Comment: One upvotes for your try

Answer (score 4):

You were on the right path, your regex expression only handles 1 uppercase character and 1 number/digit, you should change it to:

```
^([A-Z]{2})-([0-9]{2})$
```

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/KwIDtp/1
More informations: [Match Exactly n Times: {n}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions#match-exactly-n-times-n)

Comment: Your code is working as exactly what i need. Thanks for share your valuable time and knowledge.

Comment: I'm glad it helps, please accept this as the answer.